# Using Putty to connect to bastion...spawns lots of plink.exe

Tags: putty

So I'm trying to get putty to work to allow me to connect through a bastion host. I have everything setup correctly because it successfully connected to my server through the bastion. All of the sudden though, I try to open my connection and hundreds of "plink" processes start up and I don't know why.

Settings for Putty:

Connection->SSH->Auth: Check "Allow Agent Forwarding"

Connection->Proxy: Proxy Type = Local Local Proxy Command = "plink.exe -l -agent -nc %host:%port"

Any insight as to what I could do to find out why its creating so many "plink" process would be appreciated. It seems like its in some sort of loop but not really sure where it could be happening.

Windows 7 Putty, PLink, Pagent version: 0.63

P.S.  - I tried asking this on SuperUser but didn't get any kind of response and its a frustrating issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the problem had to do with the Connection->Proxy settings were set for the Default Settings and my particular saved session.  Once I removed them from the Default it stopped spawning multiple PLINK processes.

Comment: Glad to help 1.5 years later :)